# Running asynctasks one by one

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 3 asynctask to run.

```
new getNewArrivalProducts().execute();
new getPromo().execute();
new getUserinfo().execute();
```

It works well, But now i want to run it one by one. So i try this

```
final AsyncTask First  = new getNewArrivalProducts().execute();
final AsyncTask Second = new getPromo();
final AsyncTask Third = new getUserinfo();

     if(First.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                            inAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
                            inAnimation.setDuration(200);
                            progressBarHolder.setAnimation(inAnimation);
                            progressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        if(First.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && Second.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                            Second.execute();
                            if(Second.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED  && Third.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                                Third.execute();
                                if(Third.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED ){
                                    outAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
                                    progressBarHolder.setAnimation(outAnimation);
                                    progressBarHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But, with my script above. Only `first` is running and the others are not running. How can i make my asynctasks run by one ? thanks in advance

Comment: verify if `                        if(First.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && Second.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){` is true

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask, specifically `onPostExecute()` you can put second asynctask in `onPostExecute()` of first & same with third asynctask.

Comment: I would rather suggest you to move on with RxJava where all these boilerplates are handled very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> Call the asyntask one by one in post execute methods accordingly

First call this

```
new getNewArrivalProducts().execute();
```

**then in post execute call** new `getPromo().execute();`

```
public class getNewArrivalProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  // rest of the code here

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      new getPromo().execute();
    }
 }

public class getPromo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

   // rest of the code here

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      new getUserinfo().execute();
    }
 }

public class getUserinfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 // rest of the code here

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
 }
```